# The context processor that will pass the variable to the template year

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a context processor `core.context_processors.year.year` that will pass a variable year to the template, the value of which will be the current year as a number: © {{ year }} Copyright

```
from datetime import datetime, date

def year(request):
    return {
       request, datetime.now().date()
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to return a dictionary, not a set. That dictionary should contain as key the name of the variable, and as value the value you want to associate with that, so here this will look like:

```
from django.utils.timezone import now

def year(request):
    return {
       'year': now().year
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Built-in "now" templatetag https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/templates/builtins/#now

```
© {% now "Y" %} Copyright
```

Comment: it doesn't fit, needs a function, so that later not to change in each template

Comment: I do not think the "now" templatetag will ever change in django so you should not need to change it in your templates. It also adheres to your timezone settings similar to Willem's solution.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to do it, initially I did it wrong. Thanks to everyone who responded.

```
from datetime import datetime


def year(request):
    dt = datetime.now().year
    return {
       'year': dt
    }
```